# constructing a class with a struct inside of it c++

Tags: c++, object, nested-class, internal-class

So I have a class which holds a struct inside its private variables and inside this struct I have an array where the size of the array is only determined after the construction of the class.

```
template <typename T> 
class btree {

  public:
    btree(size_t maxNodeElems);
    ~btree() {}

  private:
    // The details of your implementation go here
    size_t maxNodeElems;
    struct node {

      list <T> elements;
      node lvl[];

    };

};
```

Firstly, do I have to make it so its `node * lvl` and how do I call the variables inside this struct? Is it the same as a private variable, so whenever I use it inside one of the functions in `btree class` I can call it be `btree.lvl` or is it `btree->node->lvl` or is there a special way to do this?

Also, my array has to be of `maxNodeElems+1` if someone can help me, that'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just declaring the type, not an actual object of that type. You need to make your struct declaration public and the object private:

```
template <typename T> 
class btree {

  public:
    btree(size_t maxNodeElems);
    ~btree() {}

    struct node {   // <- this is just a declaration of a private inner-class
      list <T> elements;
      node lvl[];
    };

  private:
    size_t maxNodeElems;
    node*  memberNode;   // <- this is the actual private member

};
```

You can create objects of that type from outside:

```
btree<A>::node* n = new btree<A>::node;
```

For accessing members, you can have public getters & setters in your btree class:

```
class btree {
public:
   node* getNode()
   {
      return memberNode;
   }
   //...........
   //...........
};
```

EDIT:

The following works for me (initializing the member):

```
template <typename T> 
class btree {

  public:
    btree()
    {
       memberNode = new btree<T>::node;
    }
    ~btree() {}

    void init()
    {
       memberNode->lvl = new node[10];
    }

    struct node {   // <- this is just a declaration of a private inner-class
      list <T> elements;
      node* lvl;
    };

  private:
    size_t maxNodeElems;
    node*  memberNode;   // <- this is the actual private member

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   btree<char> b;
   b.init();
}
```

Comment: so would this mean, I can do `n->lvl = new node[maxNodeElems+1];` if I change `node lvl[]` to `node *lvl` ?

Comment: Yes. You can do this directly inside the class (I named my variable memberNode). Struct members are public by default so this should work.

Comment: its throwing a bunch of errors when I try `memberNode = new btree<T>::node;` mainly `btree.tem:8: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'btree<char>::node*' in assignment`

Comment: how did you get that code to compile? When I run it, it spits out a tonne of errors

Comment: Note that this code contains memory leaks - it needs a destructor, copy constructor and copy assignment operator to be usable. It would be easier to use `std::vector` for `lvl` rather than than to manage a dynamic array yourself.

Comment: @MikeSeymour agreed, you should free the memory in the destructor.